# Specification for Version2 Tiff annotations, stored in external markup file

Tags: tiff, opentext

I have old Eastman/eiStream/OpenText document repositories that store TIFF images.

Some of the TIFFs are annotated, with the annotations stored in the TIFF header; these I can manage having found specs for the TIFF header layout and the layouts of the annotations themselves.

Unfortunately there are a small percentage of the TIFFs with "Version2" mark ups that are stored outside the TIFF in a `.ano` file.

Can anyone point me to a spec that could enable me to decode the contents of the `.ano` file?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't have a spec. But do you have some sample files, maybe someone could reverse-engineer the format?

Comment: @haraldK: I've looked, it's complicated, lots of binary data. I can see where the annotations start, and have a heuristic that pulls them out, but having a "best guess" algorithm that runs against a dozen samples in the office is one thing, running it against millions of historic documents on site is another. All round folks here would prefer something written from a canonical spec, me included.

Comment: The latest spec I heard of is http://web.archive.org/web/20081020231124/http://support.global360.com/content/I4W/documentation/annospec.htm. These ".ano" files may be a custom in-house extension.

Comment: Thanks @Jk1, that's what I currently have and use for the annotations embedded in the TIFF. those guys are also embedded in the .ano file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around on the OpenText website (this page: http://www.opentext.com/What-We-Do/Products/OpenText-Product-Offerings-Catalog/OpenText-Imaging-for-Windows/Image-File-Formats#Annotations) at the bottom it says this about tiff:

> TIFF
>
> Are the TIFF image documents created by Imaging for Windows compatible with other image editor/viewer products?
>   Yes. The file format is a standard TIFF 6.0 multi-page, multi-strip or single-strip format. Most TIFF 6.0 capable products are able to view the image pages. In the Imaging application, the TIFF settings reside on the ‘File Options’ dialog box.
>
> If it is desirable for other image file readers to handle the annotations generated by Imaging for Windows, the Annotation Specification is available for download.

However, I could not find the download for the specification anywhere on their site. 
Could this be the source of those .ano files? I bet they would send you the spec if you emailed them.

Comment: No, that would be the annotation specification that I already have, it shows how to read the annotations in the tiff header files. It doesn't cover this other. ano file. But thanks anyway.